# "Find and Replace" text box holds the cursor

Tags: visual-studio-2012

context, Find and Replace "window" in VS2012 (rc)

Anyone know how to either alter the behavior or get back the old find and replace?

When you execute a search in the new "Find and Replace" you can press F3 to cycle through the results (same as old behavior). However, you have to click ESC to put the active cursor location in your code. With the old setup (if you have the search window auto-close) the cursor is already in the code. Pressing down without pressing ESC requests the history of searches dropdown list to open.

Basically, I just want the old search window, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nope, this is the new search box, and the old one basically isn't available anymore.  What you can do it file a bug report on the [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback) site, but honestly it will probably be ignored because MS has decided that usability is not important for this new version of Visual Studio (in my own humble opinion)

Good luck!

As an alternate, I guess that you could make an extension that repeats the previous behaviour (like I am doing for all of my Macros) but that is kind of in the territory of overkill.

Comment: @payo when you do, please let me know as I am not a huge fan of the 'improvement'  Thanks!

Comment: The old one is available via `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F`

Comment: @bobobobo Except for the part where it isn't.  It's similar, I'll grant you that, but certainly not the same.  Also, the OP cares about usability, not looks.

Comment: Well, now I've been sufficiently annoyed by VS 2012 to say yeah, it really does suck.

Comment: @payo, Have you been able to create an extension fixing this mess?

Comment: +1 for "but honestly it will probably be ignored because MS has decided that usability is not important for this new version of Visual Studio" :D

Comment: I couldn't agree more with the usability not being important part. The VS2013 is really pathetic from usability point of view (I can't say much about 2012 as I moved from 2010 to 2013). Everything about this new version is really frustrating, to be the least.

Comment: @6packkid: Yes, the jump from 2008 to 2010 wasbig and significant, less so from 2010 to 2012, though I like 2012 better overall.  2013 on the other hand, is actually quite buggy.  I installed it on one machine, but see no reason to include others.  It's not bad by any means, but for every improvement, there is 1.5 new problems.  The 'sign in to Visual Studio' thing is COMPLETELY useless. :/

Answer (score 9):

If you hit Ctl-Shift-F or Ctl-Shift-H, you'll open the Find/Replace in files dialog, which is very similar to Visual Studio 2010. Even though it says "find in files", you have the option of searching in selected text and the current document.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the way you search in VS 2012 is `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F`, type your term, and then press `Alt`+`F`.  Try not to curse when you accidently press enter.

Answer (score 4):

Taking the information above, I went into Tools / Options / Environment / Keyboard and switched the <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd> hotkeys around.

I then dragged the "Find and Replace" window to the right and docked it as a tab (*along with Solution Explorer, Properties, etc*), as I haven't found a way to have it close automatically after starting a search.

I can now place the cursor anywhere in my document, press <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>, enter my criteria and press <kbd>F3</kbd> to start the search.

Repeated <kbd>F3</kbd>'s, even after moving the cursor, behaves just like the good-old-times! (*but as bobobobo mentions, be prepared to curse if you accidentally start your search with <kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of <kbd>F3</kbd> :(*)

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks man, thanks to you and Google and SO, I have avoided any further S&R frustration in VS2012 (and it took me about 12 seconds ;) Back to work!

Comment: You can close it again by pressing Ctrl+Shift+F, or in your case, just Ctrl+F and then Shift-Esc. A bit cumbersome, but still faster than the mouse.